# How to use UTType with a UIDocumentPicker (pages? docx?)

Tags: swift, file, types, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, uttype

I'm trying to open a picker with only certain file types allowed.
I'm using this documentation to find the UTType I need:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/system_declared_uniform_type_identifiers

But I can't find a UTType for .pages, .doc, .docx for example.

What should I do?

This is my code for the moment

```
func presentPickerDocument() {
    //Create a picker specifying file type and mode
    var supportedTypes: [UTType]
    supportedTypes = [UTType.pdf, UTType.url]

    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes, asCopy: true)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a `UTType` from a file extension like this:

```
UTType(tag: "pages", tagClass: .filenameExtension, conformingTo: nil)
```

This creates a `UTType?`, as there can be no `UTType` associated with the given file extension.

You can also use:

```
UTType(filenameExtension: "pages")
```

but this only finds a `UTType` if the file extension inherits from `public.data`, so it won't work for all the file extensions.

On macOS Terminal, you can also use the `mdls` command to inspect the Uniform Type Identifier of a file

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentType yourFile.pages
```

Or its entire tree:

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree yourFile.pages
```

After that you can create a `UTType` using its identifier like this:

```
UTType("com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages")
```

Comment: Is the tag same as the extension? Where do I get it from for arbitrary extensions?

Comment: @AmirHajiha There are many tags that a `UTType` may have, grouped into tag classes. One of them is the `.filenameExtension` tag class. See what I passed for the `tagClass` parameter there? I'm getting the `UTType` that has the `filenameExtension` tag class tag of `pages` associated with it.

Comment: @AmirHajiha So basically to answer your question, *yes*, as long as you do `tagClass: .filenameExtension`. If it can't get it from an extension, you can always use the method in the second half of the answer to view the UTType of a particular file.

Comment: There seems to be UTType.CreateFromExtension introduced in iOS 14 upwards so I will try that as well in my Xamarin.iOS project

Comment: @AmirHajiha Not very familiar with Xamarin, but I *think* that is the Xamarin.iOS version of `UTType(filenameExtension: "pages")` (my second code snippet).

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small func to convert a string array to a UTType array to use with filetypes. This works only with macOS 11 and later projects.

```
func stringarray2content (_ stringArray: [String]) -> [UTType]
{
    var contentArray: [UTType] = []
    if (stringArray.count > 0)
    {
        for i in 1...stringArray.count
        {
            contentArray.append(UTType(tag: stringArray[i], tagClass: .filenameExtension, conformingTo: nil)!)
        }
    }
    return (contentArray)
}
```

Please make sure you have included the library for UTType:

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
```

Comment: Why check the array count? Why iterate the index (which you are doing incorrectly)? Just do `for string in stringArray` and replace `stringArray[i]` with `string`.

Answer (score -1):

There is a little error in the for-loop. It must be:

```
for i in 0..<stringArray.count
```

Because 0 is the first element and count - 1 the last one. The complete function must be look like:

```
func stringarray2content (_ stringArray: [String]) -> [UTType]
{
    var contentArray: [UTType] = []
    if (stringArray.count > 0)
    {
        for i in 0..<stringArray.count
        { 
            contentArray.append(UTType(tag: stringArray[i], tagClass: .filenameExtension, conformingTo: nil)!)
        }
    }
    return (contentArray)
}
```

Comment: This should not be posted as an answer. Just post a comment below the answer you are correcting. Better yet, fix the other answer.